# MVC5 published to Azure as cloud service redirects to localhost:44300 after AD sign-in

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory, azure-cloud-services

We have developed an MVC5 application with Azure Active Directory authentication.  When deployed to Azure as a Web App everything works perfectly.  However we have been requested to deploy as a cloud service.

Created a new Cloud service project, added the MVC project as a role, added 2 endpoints HTTP/HTTPS to the Cloud service.  Created a self-signed cert and applied to the HTTPS endpoint.

**Local debug**

Everything runs fine in local debug IIS Express and Azure Compute Emulator.
Initial request directs to http://localhost:7390 (IISe http port).
Redirects to Microsoft AD signin then redirects to https://localhost:4430 (IISe https port) and after the expected certificate warning for a self-signed cert the homepage is correctly displayed.

**Azure Cloud service**

App as been pushed to Azure as a cloud service deployment.
The self-signed cert has been uploaded to Azure.

Azure Active Directory has had an entry added for the app (using the cloud service publish URL as shown below)

Sign on URL : http://xxxxxxxxtest.cloudapp.net/

APP ID URI : http://xxxxxxxxtest.cloudapp.net/

Reply ULR : http://xxxxxxxxtest.cloudapp.net/

When hitting the site http://xxxxxxxxtest.cloudapp.net/ the redirect to Microsoft AD signin occurs as expected, but following successful sign in we get redirected to *https://localhost:4430* as if it was running on local test environment.

Completely stuck on this one !

TIA
Martin.

Comment: Please check if the redirect URL (`https://localhost:4430`) has been hardcoded in the application where you are creating the URL for redirecting to Azure AD for auth.

Comment: I created a new test app from scratch (A cloud service with a single web role MVC - just a basic default index page app) after our main app had this problem.  The test app exhibits exactly the same issue.  The test app is using my own MSDN Azure account - which was completely clean before publishing the cloud service.  There are no hard coded redirects I can find in web.config of the main or test app.. It's really puzzling me !  Only place 4430 occurs is F4 properties SSL URL of the MVC project for Development server?

Comment: Try to run fiddler alongside your application when you load it to verify where the redirect is coming from.

My first guess would also have been the redirect URL in Azure AD. Check using fiddler where Azure AD redirects after the the authentication happens. This way you can pin point if it's a configuration problem in Azure AD or an issue in your MVC application.

Comment: fiddler shows xxxxxxxxtest.cloudapp.net --> login.windows.net --> Tunnel to login.windows.net:443 --> Tunnel to aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com:443  --> login.microsoftonline.com --> Tunnel to localhost:44300

Comment: Examining the raw data from login.microsoft.com
GET/xxxxxhotmail.onmicrosoft.com/wsfed?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2fxxxxxhotmail.onmicrosoft.com%2fWebRole1&wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3dpassive%26ru%3d%252f&wct=2015-10-13T11%3a48%3a38Z

<html><head><title>Working...</title></head><body><form method="POST" name="hiddenform" action="https://localhost:44300/">

Answer (score 5):

I've fixed this issue.

The APP ID URI in Azure Active Directory / Application did not match the values defined in the web.config in the following keys

- ida:Realm
- ida:AudienceUri

In Azure navigate to Active Directory / Applications.
Select the Application and navigate to Configure 
Grab the APP ID URI value. For my test app I set this to

http://xxxxxxxxtest.cloudapp.net/WebRole

Edit the web.config

the ida:Realm and ida:AudienceUri values must match the APP ID URI

the realm value must matche the APP ID URI

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://login.windows.net/yyyyyyyy.onmicrosoft.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
    **<add key="ida:Realm" value="http://xxxxxxxxtest.cloudapp.net/WebRole" />**
    **<add key="ida:AudienceUri" value="http://xxxxxxxxtest.cloudapp.net/WebRole"/>**
</appSettings>

<system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://login.windows.net/yyyyyyyy.onmicrosoft.com/wsfed" 
                    **realm="http://xxxxxxxxtest.cloudapp.net/WebRole"** requireHttps="true" />
    </federationConfiguration>
</system.identityModel.services>
```

After ensuring that these matched the web app runs correctly after logging in via Microsoft Active Directory.

It seems that the redirect to https://localhost:44300 is a fallback if the URI doesn't match.

The values for local development defined in the MVC properties for "Development server" SSL URL (which can be accessed by highlighting the MVC project in the solution and pressing F4) are published with the app to the cloud service and used if all is not well following AD authentication.  I confirmed this by changing the SSL URL to localhost:44313, breaking the configuration and it did indeed attempt to redirect to 44313.

Comment: I found I didn't need to add ida:Realm and ida:AudienceUri. Instead, in Azure Active Directory, as you said, I:

1. Went to Settings, then Reply URLs, and removed localhost, changing it to my redirect URI, 2) Made similar change for Home Page URL in Properties. It was the Reply URLs that seemed to make the true difference.